# When do end game achievements activate in The Banner Saga

Tags: steam, achievements, the-banner-saga

I just finished a hard-mode play through of The Banner Saga and the achievements did not activate. I'm on Mac playing a Steam version. I was on a spotty internet connection at the time, which has interfered with Steam achievements in the past.

I'm trying to figure out how far back to load a save to replay and activate the achievements. I just tried it from after the final boss fight and no dice. Do I just have to replay the fight? Or go back further?